# Rendering regex data to Jade

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, pug

So in my code below, I write the data extracted from the regex matches onto the console. However, I need to render this data to a jade file so the user, who uploads the log file, can view the matches himself. Any ideas or sites with information?

```
while ((match = reDiaBtoa.exec(newArray[j])) != null) {

if (match.index === reDiaBtoa.lastIndex) {
reDiaBtoa.lastIndex++;
}

if (match[2] === "ERROR") {

console.log(match[2]);
console.log("Time " + match[1]);
console.log("Thread Name: " + match[3]);
console.log("Source name & line number: " + match[4]);
console.log("Log Message: " + match[5] + '\n');
console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------------" + "\n");

var logs = [new Log(match[1], match[3], match[4], match[5])]
}    
}
```

UPDATE: So this is what I have tried so far.

Jade file:

```
...
  form(method="post", action="/upload", enctype="multipart/form-data")
      input(type="file", name="logName")
      button(type="submit") Upload

   h1.
        Log List
    #logs
        for log in logs
            include log
```

With this code in my index.js file

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('fileUpload', { title: 'Building a Log File Viewer' }, {logs: logs});
});


function Log(time, thread, source, mess) {
    this.time = time;
    this.thread = thread;
    this.source = source;
    this.mess = mess;
}
```

But it renders an error that logs is undefined. I'm supposing since it does not put the matches into the log entries.

Comment: Put it into an array, and pass that to Jade?

Answer (score 0):

```
res.render('fileUpload', { title: 'Building a Log File Viewer' }, {logs: logs});
```

should be

```
res.render('fileUpload', { title: 'Building a Log File Viewer', logs: logs });
```

I think that will get `logs` to be the array inside the jade template, but I don't think your `include log` is going to treat `log` as a variable, it's just going to try to include a file called "log.jade". You'll probably need to read the log files in your javascript code to get the data you need as strings and then pass that to jade for inclusion in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, it keeps saying logs is not defined. I used the include log to include the file called log.jade that laid out log.thread, log.source, log.mess. And I do read in the log files using fileRead but then I parse through the data with a regex.